# Connect to the same database but localhost datetime difference vs server host datetime

Tags: sql-server, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using AngularJS v1.7.2, ASP.NET Core MVC, SQL Server. I have a problem with field Datetime load from db. Something like below:

In database server from Korea.

[image]

In MVC C#

```
DateCreated = (DateTime)row["DateCreated"]
```

In AngularJS HTML

```
<span >{{l.DateCreated | utc | date:'yy-MM-dd HH:mm'}}</span>
```

The result when an user login web from Vietnam

```
19-12-06 9:54
19-12-12 4:05
```

The result when an user login web from Korea

```
19-12-06 11:54
19-12-12 6:05
```

Why it difference? How can I display true DateCreated like database.

Expect result:

```
19-12-06 7:54
19-12-12 9:05
```

---

### Update

return from server by get in angularjs ajax:

```
/Date(1575586450387+0900)/,
/Date(1576109127083+0900)/
```

Comment: when you put breakpoint in MVC action, what dates do you see? Also, can you try removing "| utc" in angular code?

Comment: @sam datetime return from server by get in angularjs ajax: /Date(1575586450387+0900)/, /Date(1576109127083+0900)/

Comment: Also, are those dates in database are in korean time zone (Seoul) or in UTC?

Comment: You need to make it clear: If the time in your database is an UTC time or a local time.

Comment: I guess this is because of `utc` filter. Can you show it's code?

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert the data from the server to JavaScript Date objects:

```js
var dateArr = ["/Date(1575586450387+0900)/","/Date(1576109127083+0900)/"];

function mvcToJsDate(str) {
     var s1 = str.slice(6);
     var n1 = parseInt(s1);
     var d1 = new Date(n1);
     return d1;
}

dateArr.forEach( _ => console.log(mvcToJsDate(_).toUTCString()) );
```